# How do I put an UIImageView in the center of a tableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I want my image to be in the center in the x axis, I'm writing this code :

```
let emptyImage=UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width)/2 ,y: 200 , width: 50, height: 50))
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: You need a custom UITableViewCell object.

Comment: You have to provide more information. What 's mean of  "doesn't work"? -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are trying to create image in code. Try adding anchors between imageView and tableview. Find below peace of example code.

```
    let emptyImage = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: ""))
    view1.backgroundColor = UIColor.black // view1 consider this as your tableview
    emptyImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false //missed it in first place
    self.view1.addSubview(emptyImage)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            emptyImage.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view1.centerXAnchor),
            emptyImage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view1.centerYAnchor),
            emptyImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
            emptyImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
        ])
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: its says "argument passed to call that takes no arguments"

Comment: missed open `[` added it now. Please give it a try

Comment: Oh thats weird, Just trying to understand the problem. When you say you want to set image view to center of tableview, Are you adding image view as subview to tableview or to view controller view ? Because above code works fine for me.

Comment: yes I am adding image as a subView, I want the image to be in the centre from both x and y axis.

Comment: still throws the `SIGABRT` with error "because they have no common ancestor"

Comment: I believe your are not adding image view as subview to tableview, thats the reason you are getting that error. In my code replace view1 with self.view inside NSLayoutConstraint code block

Comment: Thanks..It worked, I had my `self.view.addSubview(emptyImage)` out of the code block.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
let emptyImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2 - 50/2, y: 200, width: 50, height : 50)
```

Comment: while this may or may not be correct, a small explanation as to why yours is supposed to work as opposed to what the thread starter has, might make it a so much nicer answer

Answer (score 0):

Try setting imageView center property to tableView.center:

```
imageView.center = tableView.center
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show an UIImageView instead of cells, then try this:

```
  let emptyImage=UIImageView(frame: 
                             CGRect(x: 0, 
                                    y: 0, 
                          width:   self.tableView.bounds.size.width,            
                          height: self.tableView.bounds.size.height))

  self.tableView.backgroundView = emptyImage
```